# SVG PATH to curve borders between sections works wrong on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

In the website I am coding I used svg path to curve the border of both top and bottom sections of the webpage. Everything seems to work good when I use large screens, but if I try with mobile devices the curve sticks too up (or too down) and cover the text inside the section. Any idea how I can fix this? I would like to maintain this design also for mobile devices. To let understand better my problem here I placed some pics

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  padding: 0 /* 1rem */;
}

/* -------- NAV2 ----------- */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  border-top: 0.5rem solid #fff;
  background-color: #f2a900;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row; */
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  border-top: 0.5rem solid #f2a900;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: 0 1.2rem 3.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}


.logo2 {
  height: 5.2rem;
}

nav ul {
  height: 100%;
}

.header ul,
.header2 ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.header ul li,
.header2 ul li {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding-right: 1.8rem;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------- Header primary ----------- */

.main-nav-link2 {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav-link2:link,
.main-nav-link2:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.main-nav-link2:hover,
.main-nav-link2:active {
  color: #fceecc;
}

.main-nav-link2.nav-cta2:link,
.main-nav-link2.nav-cta2:visited {
  padding: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #da9800;
}

.main-nav-link2.nav-cta2:hover,
.main-nav-link2.nav-cta2:active {
  background-color: #c28700;
  color: #fceecc;
}

#hamburger-icon2 {
  margin: auto 3rem auto 0;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-icon2 div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* ---------- Header Secondary ----------- */

.main-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav-link:link,
.main-nav-link:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2a900;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.main-nav-link:hover,
.main-nav-link:active {
  color: #c28700;
}

.main-nav-link.nav-cta:link,
.main-nav-link.nav-cta:visited {
  padding: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f2a900;
}

.main-nav-link.nav-cta:hover,
.main-nav-link.nav-cta:active {
  background-color: #c28700;
  color: #fceecc;
}

#hamburger-icon {
  margin: auto 3rem auto 0;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-icon div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #f2a900;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.open .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
}

.open .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
}

.open .mobile-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.5rem;
  left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  width: 100%;
}

.mobile-menu li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

/* ----- start main header dropdwon menu ------- */

.open .mobile-menu2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: hsla(42, 100%, 47%, 0.8);
}

.mobile-menu2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.5rem;
  left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.mobile-menu2 li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

/* ------ end main header dropddown menu --------*/

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: moveInLeft;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.price {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  place-items: center;
  padding-top: 9.6rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 85vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      rgba(242, 169, 0, 0.5),
      rgba(242, 169, 0, 0.5)
    ),
    url(../images/moscow-city.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.value1 h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hero-txt {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1.5rem auto;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.hero-txt2 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
}

.hero-btn {
  padding: 1.6rem;
  background-color: #f2a900;
  border-radius: 1.8rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  color: #fceecc;
}

.hero-btn-container a,
a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.svg-1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.svg-2 {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.hero h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

.lang {
  margin: 2rem auto 1.6rem auto;
}

.fi {
  font-size: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.fi:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="header">
        <div id="brand">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="logo2" alt="bitcoin atm moscow logo" src="images/logo.png" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="main-nav-link2" href="#about">About us</a></li>
            <li><a class="main-nav-link2" href="#benefit">How to buy</a></li>
            <li>
              <a class="main-nav-link2 nav-cta2" href="#map">Where we are</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="main-nav-link2" href="#why-box">Why us</a></li>
            <li><a class="main-nav-link2" href="#footer">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="hamburger-icon2" onclick="toggleMobileMenu(this)">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
          <ul class="mobile-menu2">
            <li><a class="main-nav-link2" href="#about">About us</a></li>
            <li><a class="main-nav-link2" href="#benefit">How to buy</a></li>
            <li>
              <a class="main-nav-link2 nav-cta2" href="#map">Where we are</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="main-nav-link2" href="#why-box">Why us</a></li>
            <li><a class="main-nav-link2" href="#footer">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="header2 hide" id="header2">
      <div id="brand">
        <a href="#">
        <img class="logo2" alt="bitcoin atm moscow logo" src="images/logo2.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#header">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#about">About us</a></li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#benefit">How to buy</a></li>
          <li>
            <a class="main-nav-link nav-cta" href="#map">Where we are</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#why-box">Why us</a></li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#footer">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="hamburger-icon" onclick="toggleMobileMenu(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
        <ul class="mobile-menu">
        <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#header">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#about">About us</a></li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#benefit">How to buy</a></li>
          <li>
            <a class="main-nav-link nav-cta" href="#map">Where we are</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#why-box">Why us</a></li>
          <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#footer">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="hero">
  <div class="lang">
  <a href="index.php" title="русский" class="fi fi-ru fis"> </a>
    <a href="index_en.php" title="english" class="fi fi-gb fis"></a>
    <a href="index_it.php" title="italiano" class="fi fi-it fis"></a>
  </div>

          <div class="hero-txt"><h2>Only 21 millions of Bitcoins will be created and we are more than 8 billions in this world:<br></h2>
           <div class="hero-txt2"> <h2>what are you waiting to get yours?</div></h2>
</div>

<div class="hero-btn-container">
  <a href="#map-box" class="hero-btn">Buy Bitcoin</a>
  </div>



  
       <svg
          class="svg-1"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 1424 224"
        >
          <path
            fill="#f2a900"
            fill-opacity="1"
            d="M0,32L120,58.7C240,85,480,139,720,138.7C960,139,1200,85,1320,58.7L1440,32L1440,320L1320,320C1200,320,960,320,720,320C480,320,240,320,120,320L0,320Z"
          ></path>
        </svg>
        <svg
          class="svg-2"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 1440 220"
        >
          <path
            fill="#fff"
            fill-opacity="1"
            d="M0,32L120,58.7C240,85,480,139,720,138.7C960,139,1200,85,1320,58.7L1440,32L1440,320L1320,320C1200,320,960,320,720,320C480,320,240,320,120,320L0,320Z"
          ></path>
        </svg>
        <div class="cta"></div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

. The site is also online at btcatm.ru
Here is [[image: large][1]]how appear the website in a large screen (for example through a MacBook)

And here through a small device, for example an iPhone:

[[image: small][2]]

Comment: You've set the height of the hero to a fixed value. With `min-height` you can either let the content control the height, or the min value on bigger screens.

Comment: So in my case what should I put instead “height: 85vh “? Do I need to change it only in media queries?

Answer (score -5):

You mentioned that your website mobile is working properly and using the SVG way you have curved the edges of the top and bottom of the web page. Everything seems to work fine on large screens, but on mobile the curved part is too high or too low and takes up text within the partition
It is important that you use the  tag for correct display of mobile devices. Correct view settings help the device detect the screen width and scale the content correctly. For example, you can use the following tag:

Comment: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)